# error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python.gi/info/refs

Tags: github, alchemyapi

I am trying to use alchemy api for entity extraction

```
https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python
```

When i give this command to clone

```
git clone https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python.git
```

I get this error:

The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python.gi/info/refs
fatal: HTTP request failed

Please let me know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and debug it with GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 before git clone.
You also can try cloning it with ssh:

```
git clone git@github.com:AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_python
```

(Make sure [your public ssh key is registered first](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) and that `ssh -Tv git@github.com` works)

I just cloned it with the https url without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Download the code as zip file. There is option on bottom-right corner.